# Aria attributes not changing with fireEvents on using jest and react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, wai-aria

React testing library's fireevent is working with everything else but  aria attributes like aria-checked or other aria attributes when i try to test it just dosnt get updated on firing the fireevents.Is it a known issue or do i have to do something for aria-checked to change in testing dom too.

Comment: Could you reproduce in a codesandbox ?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without code being posted, but I've ran into similar issues myself when those aria attributes are tied to the state object of the react component. If that is the case, because the updating of state is asynchronous, when the `click` event is fired, unless you `await` the change of state (which in this case would result in a change in the HTML aria attributes`), the test moves on and runs the assertion against the rendered component before the state update is complete, resulting in a failed tests.

To give a hand wavy code example of what I mean, if your `aria-checked` attribute is tied to state, this test would fail:

```
  fireEvent.click(locator_to_your_element);
  expect(locator_to_your_element).toBeChecked();
```

Instead you would need to test it something like this:

```
  fireEvent.click(locator_to_your_element);
  await waitFor(() => expect(locator_to_your_element).toBeChecked());
```

This tells jest to wait for the attr to change. Docs on the `waitFor` method can be found [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/)